# clojure like cond in F#

Tags: clojure, f#

I was recently taking a detour in clojure from F# and came across a macro called cond. 
Here is an example on the usage:

```
(cond
 (= target (nth arr mid)) mid  
 (< target (nth arr mid)) (search left (- mid 1))
 (> target (nth arr mid)) (search (+ mid 1) right)
 (= left right) -1)
```

This means the following in pseudo code:

```
if target == arr.[mid] then return mid
if target < arr.[mid] then return (call search(left, mid-1)) 
if target > arr.[mid] then return (call search(mid+1, right))
if left == right then return -1
```

This is just an example from a binary search in case you were wondering what is left right and mid, but not really important.

I have tried to find something similar in F# but I couldn't, so I decided to try and write it for myself.
I ended up with something like this:

```
type condition = bool * int

let cond (conds: condition seq) = 
    conds |> Seq.pick(fun c -> if fst c then Some (snd c) else None)

cond [| ( (=) target arr.[mid], mid )
        ( (=) left right, -1 ) 
        ( (<) target arr.[mid], recSrch left (mid-1) )
        ( (>) target arr.[mid], recSrch (mid+1) right )
      |]
```

The problem here is that I want to use it in a recursive function, and because recSrch left (mid-1) are being evaluated right away so I end up in an infinite loop. I want it to be evaluated only when the condition holds. Plus the form is still not as clean as it is in Clojure.

Any ideas how could I improve this?

Comment: For those of us who don't know Clojure your question is extremely opaque.

Comment: Sorry for that, I added some pseudo code to make it clear how does the clojure code behaves.

Comment: Can you post the full code, including ``target``, ``left``, ``right``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a way of making the condition bodies evaluate lazily. Here's one way of doing it, by making the body a function to call as you iterate through the sequence of conditions:

```
type condition = bool * (unit -> int)

let cond (conds: condition seq) = 
    conds 
    |> Seq.pick(fun c -> 
        let pred, func = c
        if pred then Some (func()) else None)

cond [| ( (=) target arr.[mid], fun () -> mid )
        ( (=) left right, fun () -> -1 ) 
        ( (<) target arr.[mid], fun () -> recSrch left (mid-1) )
        ( (>) target arr.[mid], fun () -> recSrch (mid+1) right )
        |]
```

Note that it only makes sense to use something like this if your list of conditions is supposed to be dynamic.

For static conditions, you have pattern matching with `when` clauses. That gives you nice idiomatic syntax and generally checks your matches exhaustiveness at compile time, so it's well worth it.

```
let result = 
    match target with
    | _ when target = arr.[mid] -> mid
    | _ when left = right -> -1
    | _ when target < arr.[mid] -> recSrch left (mid-1)    
    | _ when target > arr.[mid] -> recSrch (mid+1) right
    | _ -> failwith "you need this case if the compiler can't figure if your matches are exhaustive"
```

Gets nicer if you wrap it as an active pattern.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sketch using `match` which I think is pretty close to the clojure.

It defines `Cond` as a partial active pattern which takes the test function as an argument

```
let (|Cond|_|) f  arg = 
    if f arg then Some () else None;;
```

using it is pretty easy

```
match 1 with
|Cond ( (=) 5) _ -> printfn "unlikely"
| _ -> printfn "likely";;
```

Answer (score 4):

In F#, there's a language construct for that kind of expression:

```
if target = arr.[mid] then mid
elif target < arr.[mid] then call (search(left, mid-1)) 
elif target > arr.[mid] then call (search(mid+1, right))
else -1
```

...or, in general: I view Clojure's `cond` macro as the equivalent of pattern matching or `if/elif/else` blocks. They're obviously not quite the same, because Clojure is interpreted and dynamically typed, whereas F# is compiled and statically typed.

Comment: The main difference with match expression and match is evaluating on one condition, while with cond you can test different conditions as well.

Comment: @PeterV Yes, that's the reason I provided the `if/elif/else` example here, instead of pattern matching.

Comment: True, that solves the problem. What I really wanted is to create a similar construct to the cond macro in clojure, mostly because I like how compact it is. You could argue whether if it makes sense or not. It  is mostly just code ping-pong. I kinda like these though as I think I can learn a lot about the languages.